# Jscript create folder if not exist

Tags: windows, jscript, wsh

I am trying to create folder when it does not exist. If folder is exist it will skip and continue to create the next folder.

Which part is wrong in this following code,

### Error

```
Micrsoft Jscript runtime error: File already exists
```

### Code

```
   function CreateFolder(fldr)
    {
       if (fso.FolderExists(fldr)){
          return;
          }
       else 
        fso.CreateFolder("C:\\"+ fldr);
    }
```

Comment: What value does `fldr` have?

Comment: i managed to resolve it via try/catch, because it throw an error and stop after an item exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `fldr` doesn't include the drive letter, `FolderExists` looks for this folder in the current wording directory. But your code then creates this folder in `C:\`. Most likely, the error occurs because there's no folder with this name in the current working directory, but it exists in `C:\`.

Your code should probably be either

```js
function CreateFolder(fldr)
{
  if (! fso.FolderExists(fldr))
    fso.CreateFolder(fldr);
}
```

or

```js
function CreateFolder(fldr)
{
  var path = fso.BuildPath("C:", fldr);

  if (! fso.FolderExists(path))
    fso.CreateFolder(path);
}
```

Comment: ur 2nd method works, i tried with first method still throw error and stop

Comment: fldr only contail Folder name , example MyFolder